# asp.net mvc4 dropdownlist returns model displayed in same view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I have been trying to figure out how to pass a value retreaded from a dropdownlist back to a view with the same dropdownlist displayed with the results

Controller:

```
//
// GET: /ProductByID/

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProductById()
{
    ViewBag.IDNumbers = ddlItems;
    return View();
}


//
// POST: /ProductByID/

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductById(FormCollection formdata)
{
    string selected = formdata["IDNumbers"];
    int id = int.Parse(selected);
    Product p = items.GetByID(id);
    return View(p);
}
```

The View:

```
@model ProductsMVC_Basic.Models.Product

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product By Id";
}


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#IDNumbers").change(function () {
            if ($("#IDNumbers").val() != "") {
                this.form.submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ProductById", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("IDNumbers", "--Select One--") 
    }

</div>
```

This works as far as populating the dropdownlist and sending the formdata back to the controller. My question is how would I display the model data in the post view so the dropdown is displayed and the models data is also displayed like name and category etc.

Every time I post back to the same view I get an error stating "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'IDNumbers'." in the PostView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the reason of

> "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key
>   'IDNumbers'."

Because, this **DropdownList** will bind data from ViewBag/ViewData with name = `"IDNumbers"`

In your [Post]Action, There is no **Viewbag.IDNumbers** ! => so that is why you got that error.

The solution:

1.Redirect to [GET] ProductById after you receive data.

> ```
> [HttpGet]
> public ActionResult ProductById(int iMyCode)
> {
>     ViewBag.IDNumbers = ddlItems;//set your default value here
>     return View();
> }
> ```

2.Reload your Page with URL `Query String` instead of submit form.

3.Set your default value (dropdown list) in Client Side by Javascript, get your addition data from server though AJAX. Store these value by Cookie/Session/Query String.

I hope this will help

Comment: Thanks @hungdoan. And while #2 & #3 are helpful for future reference it doesn't solve my issue with displaying the returned product on the same page. This is very basic without database support (using a ProductList Class to simulate database) I try to check if the model is null such as @if(!(Model.Equals(null))) but this just throws and exception as does every other check to the model. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you return your view with Model Data like:
`return View(MyData);` , and then bind Model's data type by this way: `@model string` (in your [View[.cshtml,..) . Or you can bind your data to ViewBag (It will be easier to check null value)

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your example:

1. Don't know what you're trying to achieve, but it looks like you're stuck in the ASP.NET Web Forms "postback" model. No need to submit the form each time the DDL changes. A better approach would be to pass the product ID to the server via AJAX and do something with the response.
2. Don't use `FormCollection`. Use a ViewModel and bind to that in your View, then accept that as a parameter in the `[HttpPost]` action method.
3. Don't use `@Html.DropDownList`, use `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SomeDDl)`, where `SomeDddl` will be a property of type `SelectList` on your ViewModel (relates to 2) above).

So perhaps explain what you are trying to achieve, and I (and other's) can provide further help.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately I am bound to not using a ViewModel (at this time). What I am looking to do is to place the results of the lookup from the dropdownlist on the same page (or as it appears) along with the dropdownlist so that the first time the page is visited you only see the dropdownlist and after selecting some product from the dropdownlist it displays below the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using `ViewBag` to store your dropdownlist values.

Instead if you use your model properties to bind up the Dropdownlist, it will be better even when you post your data there is no way to lose your DropDownList data.

So, the answer is that just use `ViewBag.IDNumbers = ddlItems` in your post as well.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductById(FormCollection formdata)
{
    ViewBag.IDNumbers = ddlItems; //Set the ViewBag items 
    string selected = formdata["IDNumbers"];
    int id = int.Parse(selected);
    Product p = items.GetByID(id);
    return View(p);
}
```